# How to input a Class T and output a List of Class T in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working in C#. What I want to do is take as input a class definition of type T, do some processing with other information provided to the class, and end up with a List of objects of type T. Not important what the processing is.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, generics. `List<T> DoSomething<T>(T object)`

Comment: Or just `List<T> DoSomething<T>()` if you just need the type and not an actual instance.

Comment: I think I need reflection in addition to generics, in that some of the processing involves knowing what the properties of the object are. Can I reasonably say `x=T.GetType(); var p=x.GetProperties();` and so on, based on T?

Comment: @DavidStowell Doesn't sound like you need that. You should define a base class or interface for your generic parameter T, so you have compile-time safety to access the properties by using a generic constraint. Another option would be to pass a `Func<T>` as parameter to assist you in constructing the generic object.

Comment: To be honest, I don't want a base class or interface - I want this to work for any class that I throw at it. Let me be more specific.The class I'm building is a form (so I can't make it a generic class without the Designer objecting). I'm thinking creating a helper class (with a T parameter) to do the generic work would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use generics:

```
List<T> myFunction<T> (T myObject) {
  var list = new List<T>();
  //POPULATE LIST HERE
  list.Add(myObject);
  //DO OTHER STUFF
  return list;
}
```

Comment: A generic method is close, but not quite. I ended up creating a generic wrapper class of type T. It calls the Form class, which doesn't need to know about T, on an as needed basis. There is some reflection involved, as well.